# Excluding empty(Null) fields when using EntityFieldQuery query condition

Tags: 7, database

Is it possible to select all of the entities who's xyz field is empty?

I tried soemthing like this:

```
->fieldCondition('field_name', 'value', NULL, 'IS NOT NULL');
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

If you look on the [fieldCondition](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3afieldCondition/7) documentation page you will see the following warning:

> Note that entities with empty field values will be excluded from the EntityFieldQuery results when using this method.

Checking whether a field exists or not has been added to entityFieldQuery in Drupal 8, but unfortunately [won't be backported to Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1157006).

There are various methods to achieve this:

1. Using a tag and hook_query_TAG_alter as mentioned by @Clive, see [comment 4 on  the Drupal issue](http://drupal.org/node/1157006#comment-5465034) for an example ;
2. First query all non NULL entries, then query all entries excluding the previous ones, as described in @seddonym's answer and in [comment 5 on the Drupal issue](http://drupal.org/node/1157006#comment-6699312) ;
3. You can write your query using [SelectQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7) rathen than EntityfieldQuery as such:

_

```
$q = db_select('node', 'n');
$q->fields('n', array('type'))
  ->condition('n.type', 'my_node_type', '=')
  ->addJoin('LEFT', 'field_data_field_my_field', 'f', 'f.entity_id = n.nid');
$q->isNull('f.value');
$r = $q->execute();
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `!= NULL`, but you can't use `= NULL` for some reason.

This is my workaround.

```
  //Get all the entities that DO have values
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'MY_TYPE')
    ->fieldCondition('field_MY_FIELD', 'value', 'NULL', '!=');
  $result = $query->execute();

  if (is_array(@$result['registration'])) {
    //Now get all the other entities, that aren't in the list you just retrieved
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'MY_TYPE')
      ->entityCondition('entity_id', array_keys($result['MY_TYPE']), 'NOT IN');
    $result_two = $query->execute(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is that directly, no you can't (see [EntityFieldQuery does not support isNull or isNotNull](http://drupal.org/node/1157006)). If I remember rightly this is a side-effect of the fact that `EntityFieldQuery` uses only `INNER JOIN`s to join tables.

There is a workaround, though, which involves using [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7) and adding a tag to your `EntityFieldQuery`, there's an example in the last comment on the page I linked to above.

Answer (score 10):

[According to the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1343708) you can use null and isnull; it just has a specific way to write it.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_news_types', 'value', 'spotlight', '=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_photo', 'fid', 'NULL', '!=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_faculty_tag', 'tid', $value)
  ->fieldCondition('field_news_publishdate', 'value', $year. '%', 'like')
  ->range(0, 10)
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // run the query as user 1

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $news_items_nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $news_items = entity_load('node', $news_items_nids);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Drupal 7 please check the following workaround proposed [here](https://drupal.org/node/1157006#comment-7634027):

> Register the tag to alter the query instance:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_query_node_is_not_tagged_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_tags', 'o', 'node.nid = o.entity_id AND o.entity_type = :entity_type');
  $query->isNull('o.field_tags_tid');
}
?>
```

> Obs.: This query tag alter only works for the "node" entity type.
>   Don't confuse "field_tags" related to the "Tags" vocabulary, can be
>   any other like "Categories".
>
> Get all the nodes from that doesn't been tagged yet using
>   EntityFieldQuery, look at the addTag() method:

```
<?php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'news')
  ->addTag('node_is_not_tagged')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$result = $query->execute();
?>
```

Other example:

```
  $result = $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'my_content_type')
    ->fieldCondition('field_mine_one', 'value', '', '<>')
    ->fieldCondition('field_mine_two', 'value', '', '<>')
    ->addTag('my_custom_tag')
    ->deleted(FALSE)
    ->propertyOrderBy('changed', 'DESC')
    ->range(0, $my_range_value)
    ->execute();
```

> Then I implemented `hook_query_TAG_alter` leveraging the fact that
>   `my_custom_tag` is only set by me:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_query_TAG_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_other', 'o', 'node.nid = o.entity_id');
  $query->isNull('o.field_other_value');
}
```

Another example:

```
<?php
  //Get all the entities that DO have values
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'MY_TYPE')
    ->fieldCondition('field_MY_FIELD', 'value', 'NULL', '!=');
  $result = $query->execute();

  if (is_array(@$result['registration'])) {
    //Now get all the other entities, that aren't in the list you just retrieved 
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'MY_TYPE')
      ->entityCondition('entity_id', array_keys($result['MY_TYPE']), 'NOT IN');
    $result_two = $query->execute();  
  }
?>
```

---

More complete example below which loads bunch of nodes on cron task which empty taxonomy term references and apply some changes:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function MYMODULE_cron() {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'property')
    ->propertyOrderBy('changed', 'DESC')
    ->addTag('type_is_null')
    ->range(0,50); // Maximum of 50.
  $result = $query->execute();

  if (!empty($result['node'])) {
    $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      // do_some_stuff($node);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_query_type_is_null_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_foo', 'f', 'node.nid = f.entity_id AND f.entity_type = :entity_type');
  $query->isNull('f.field_foo_tid'); // Check name by SQL: DESC field_data_field_foo

  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_bar', 'b', 'node.nid = b.entity_id AND b.entity_type = :entity_type');
  $query->isNull('b.field_bar_tid'); // Check name by SQL: DESC field_data_field_bar
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap Null in quotes.

```
->fieldCondition('field_name', 'value', 'NULL', '!=');
```

Answer (score 2):

Please correct me if I'm wrong. It seems that it simply needs to be

`$query->fieldCondition('field_name');`

to exclude all nodes with an empty `field_name` field o_O

Tested in Drupal `version >= 7.43`.

Comment: That actually works. They more upvoted answers were erroring out for me (couldn't get it to display an error, but was breaking everything).