# Check not NULL in entityfieldquery propertyCondition

Tags: entities, database

I want to only return results in entityfieldquery that have a propertyCondition of 'field_entry_path' that is not empty.

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'example')
        ->propertyCondition('field_entry_path', '', 'NOT IN');
  $result = $query->execute();
```

Thanks.

Comment: According to the docs it _is_ possible. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26128/when-using-entityfieldquery-is-there-a-way-to-exclude-entities-when-a-specific-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs it is possible. See [Excluding empty(Null) fields when using EntityFieldQuery query condition](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26128/)
@Clive

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is impossible at the moment. See the workaround described on http://drupal.org/node/1226622.