# Trying to list all articles where category field is empty

Tags: 7, nodes

I have drupal 7 site and I'm trying to listing all articles (with title) and where category field is empty (taxonomy). I'm running this code in my page with ->isNull and without, but not any results. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong in here and why this is not working?

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('n.type', 'article') 
  ->condition('n.status', 1)
  ->isNull('n.field_tags')
  ->range(0, 10);

  $results = $query->execute();
```

I'm get this error all the time:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'n.field_tags' in 'where clause': SELECT n.nid AS nid FROM {node} n
>   WHERE (n.type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (n.status =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (n.field_tags IS NULL ) LIMIT 10
>   OFFSET 0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => article
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1 ) in eval() (line 17 of
>   /sites/site.com/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! And `->condition('n.field_tags', NULL)` or `->condition('n.field_tags', [])`? Ah yeah, same, column not found...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excluding empty(Null) fields when using EntityFieldQuery query condition](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26128/excluding-emptynull-fields-when-using-entityfieldquery-query-condition)

Comment: Just tried it myself and you definitely might go for @Clive's answer over in the linked duplicate issue with EFQ and a custom query tag. Also read through the drupal.org issue they linked in their answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me your mistake is you are requesting the column field_tags from the table node, which is not a column from node, so doesn't exist.

Unless you have a very specific database structure, your "field_tags" should be contained in the table `field_data_field_tags`, so you may have to make an `INNER JOIN` between these tables in your query (maybe using `field_data_field_tags.entity_id = n.id`), and then check if the `n.id` exists in `field_data_field_tags.entity_id`, or (maybe better) use a `LEFT JOIN` between `field_data_field_tags` and `node`, so only the node with a n.id existing in field_data_field_tags will be returned.